# For loop repeats first iteration twice - python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am having the following problem in a python script:
I have a simple for loop that iterates thru a list of lists and passes 2 parameters for another function to go fetch some data.

Running debug I see the loop works fine thru all 6 items in the for loop without any issues, but then, for some strange reason, it tries to repeat the first pair of parameters once again.

At that point I get a pandas error: "Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects" (the for loop passes parameters to a function that slices a bigger df, though I don´t think its relevant for this issue.) Important to say that first time the loop runs thru that combination, it works fine.

Anyone has come across anything like this before?

Trying a graphical explanation:

```
Params = [[a,b],[c,d],[e,f],[g,h],[i,j],[k,l]]
For item in Params:
  df' = df.loc[[df['A'] == item]
```

What I am saying is par [a,b] goes thru twice, throwing the pandas error in its "second" pass.

Adding a more complete code as requested:

data = pd.DataFrame ['Contains a datetime index of dates, a column called 'name' with values such as 'A','S','F' and 100 others and a column called 'value' for each date and name], what the code tries to accomplish is slice it down to a leaner df containing a subset of 'name' and 'value' within a certain date range (start,end) so I can use and manipulate more easily elsewhere in my code.

pairs = [['A', 'S'], ['A', 'F'], ['S', 'A'], ['S', 'F'], ['F', 'A'], ['F', 'S']], pairs contains all permutations of a subset of columns of "data", in this case, 3 columns selected to go thru 'call_pair_data', hence, 6 permutations.

Code itself:

```
for index, item in enumerate(pairs):
 x = item[0]
    y = item[1]
    df = call_pair_data(x, y, start, end)

def call_pair_data(x, y, start, end):
    df_x = data.loc[start : end]
    df_x = df_x.loc[df_x['name'] == x]
    df_y = data.loc[start : end]
    df_y = df_y.loc[df_y['name'] == y]
    pair_df = pd.merge(df_x,df_y, on=['Date'], suffixes=['_x','_y'])
    return(pair_df)
```

Comment: That's not your code, because of course there's no problem with that code.  Python is not going to arbitrarily run your loop again.  My guess is that you are modifying your list as part of the processing, so it tries to run them again.

Comment: we can't run this code to see this problem - so we can't help you. Better show minimal working code which we could copy and run.

Comment: @TimRoberts and furas, sorry... I will try an edit above to improve it. Tried to simplify because this comes from a larger code that´be difficult to replicate (I am fairly new to python). Come back shortly.

Comment: Managed to find the solution -- Tim / furas you were right, nothing wrong with the code above, the error was elsewhere causing "x" value passed thru this code to compare in [df_x['name'] == x] to be wrong, causing the error, but this was in another call of the "call_pair_data" function and not on the one above.... happy to know "for" still works and I am the dummy. @TimRoberts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `.isin()` method would be much simpler and efficient:

```
for pair in pairs: 
    res_df = df.loc[(df[start:end]) & (df['name'].isin(pair))]
```

Or

```
for pair in pairs
    res_df = df[start:end].loc[df['name'].isin(pair)]
```

This method takes a list or tuple as argument, so this would be valid too;

```
for pair in pairs: 
    res_df = df[start: end].loc[df['name'].isin([pair[0], pair[1]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, my code is far from clean... so, it helped me beyond the question (which was solved as noted above).

Comment: No problem. Pandas has so many 'obscure' methods, it's always good to check if one of them does what you want first.